# Validate a lineItem option within a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, plugin-craftcommerce

I have a lineItem option that needs validation. It’s actually an input field that can’t be blank, and different to the lineItem’s note.

The docs for [Add to Cart](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/add-to-cart#line-item-options-and-notes) mention using [onBeforeAddToCart](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_cart.onbeforeaddtocart) but it also needs to be validated if a customer decides to edit this field in the cart so perhaps `commerce_cart.onBeforeAddToCart` is not the right event here.

Can anyone offer an example of how to do this? This needs to be server-side validation, not front-end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've achieved something similar but used `commerce_lineItems.onBeforeSaveLineItem`.

This event is fired every time a line item is created or edited. Fired on `/updateCart` (product page) or `/updateLineItem` (cart page).

You might run into problems because the lineItems in the event won't contain a post request unless its the lineItem that triggered the event through a form.

You need to grab the events line item and check it against the lineItemId in the post request before doing any comparisons - unless its a new lineItem.

```
// Get the line item being saved from the event
$item = $event->params['lineItem'];

// Is this a new line item?
$isNewLineItem = $event->params['isNewLineItem'];

// Get the line item id that triggered the save from the post request
// (this will only exist if we're updated a line item that currently exists)
$lineItemId = craft()->request->getPost( 'lineItemId' );

// If the current line item being saved is new
// OR
// If its an existing line item and matches the one that triggered the event
if ( $isNewLineItem || $item->id == $lineItemId ) {
  //rest of the code
}
```

I then looked to see if the option was in the post request.

`$text = craft()->request->getPost( 'options.Text' );`

If it wasn't I added a flash message and stopped the action.

```
$event->performAction = false;
craft()->userSession->setFlash( "itemError", "You must add some text before adding this product to your basket" );
```

Comment: If you run into problems with line items being new/edited check my latest edits